# Can't find decleration file for mapboxgl

Tags: react-native, mapbox-gl

I am having trouble implementing MapboxGL into my react-native app. When hovering the import I get the following error:

> Could not find a decleration file for module "@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl".

The suggestion of installing in from '@types' doesn't work either. 
Is there a solution for this problem or an alternative for the map?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That error is just informing you that no `d.ts` file is packaged with the library. IDEs use `d.ts` files to show helpful things like tooltips describing the usage of methods, etc.; for example:

[image]

However, this is not strictly necessary to use `@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl`. You can also just look at [the docs](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl#documentation).